# Which one is better <object> or <iframe>

Tags: html, object, iframe, tags

I need to embed an interactive application (Dash app) hosted in a different domain than my website. I can do it by using both iframe and object tags in HTML, but which one is better to use?

There are some bad reputation about iframe about seo. Security is not a problem because the app is mine. Besides, I saw this comment about iframe: "One reason to use object over iframe is that object re-sizes the embedded content to fit the object dimensions. Most notable on safari in iPhone 4s where screen width is 320px and the HTML from the embedded URL may set dimensions greater."

So what should I use?

Comment: honestly, i'd try both. you can save them and peek at them in your favorite browser(s). try it on a phone. i do this a million times when im building sites.

I've used iFrames many times successfully

Comment: but this seo issue is important for me. How about this? There are some information about object is okey with seo but iframe is not.

Comment: i understand. My comment was simply to try both approaches in general. If you feel that one of the elements give you an seo advantage, maybe that's the answer.

good luck